# iPhone4s, iPhone 5 max FFTs per second using vDSP

Tags: iphone, ios, fft, vdsp

My team and I are planning to build an external accessory for iOS that will sample ultrasonic sound at 256KHZ. It's a lot and I am wondering whether iOS vDSP can do the conversion from time domain to frequency domain for 256,000 samples/sec, or we need to have a hardware based solution for the FFT.

Sample projects from Apple such as aurioTouch are very helpful but I couldn't find that deals with sampling rate more than the professional audio sampling frequency. I need help figuring out the following:

1. Can vDSP FFTs process 256,000 samples/second? If not, any other creative ways to do the same aside from doing the conversion in the hardware?

The closest discussion I found related to this is

[How many FFTs per second can I do on my smartphone? (for performing voice recognition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957907/how-many-ffts-per-second-can-i-do-on-my-smartphone-for-performing-voice-recogn)

Comment: One thing you need to specify os the size of the FFT. FFT is O(n log n) so n can make a significant difference to overall throughput. Also you should specify whether you plan to overlap your FFTs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. At this time we are not sure what will be optimal value for n. n will be 256 frames.  And yes, the plan is to overlap FFTs.

Comment: A couple thousand 256-element FFTs is a pretty trivial amount of computation.  Modern smartphones are real computers and handle this easily.

Answer (score 2):

A 256 kHz data rate is less than 6 times faster than normal 44100 audio.  And float FFTs of real-time audio data using the vDSP/Accelerate framework use only in the neighborhood of 1% or less of 1 CPU on recent iOS devices.

Answer (score 2):

The FFT computation time will be a tiny portion of the time available.

Source: I wrote the vDSP FFTs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not see how the devices handle upsampled signals, starting with aurioTouch.

If you need it faster, you should measure the speeds of an integer based FFT implementation.

Comment: We never considered the integer based FFT. Thanks for the suggestion, will look in to it.

Comment: Recent iOS devices can do float FFTs as fast or faster than scaled integer because of NEON instructions.